# Using group_by for only certain attributes

Tags: ruby, group-by, hash

I have an array `roads` of objects that have many attributes. What I would like to do is find which `district_code` (one attribute) has more than one `state` (another attribute)

Ommitting the other attributes for simplicity - eg:

```
roads = [['1004', 'VIC'], ['1004', 'BRI'], ['1011', 'VIC'], ['1010', 'ACT'], ['1000', 'ACT'], ['1019', 'VIC'], ['1004', 'VIC']]
```

If I was to use `roads.group_by { |ro| ro[0] }` I get the result:

`=> {"1004"=>[["1004", "VIC"], ["1004", "BRI"], ["1004", "VIC"]], "1011"=>[["1011", "VIC"]], "1010"=>[["1010", "ACT"]], "1000"=>[["1000", "ACT"]], "1019"=>[["1019", "VIC"]]}`

**What I want is the hash to only show where there has been more than one unique value for `state`, like so:**

```
=> {"1004"=>["VIC", "BRI"]}
```

Any ideas on how to group_by or map by the number of values / or for a specific attribute within a value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input

```
roads = [['1004', 'VIC'], ['1004', 'BRI'], ['1011', 'VIC'], ['1010', 'ACT'], ['1000', 'ACT'], ['1019', 'VIC'], ['1004', 'VIC']]
```

Code

```
p Hash[roads.group_by(&:first)
            .transform_values(&:uniq)
            .filter_map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] if v.length > 1 }]
```

Output

```
{"1004"=>["VIC", "BRI"]}
```

Comment: Nice use of Ruby v3.0's [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map).

Comment: @Cary Swoveland thank you very much.

Comment: Since `group_by` already gives you a hash you could also write `roads.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |a| a.map(&:last).uniq }.select { |_,a| a.size > 1 }`

Comment: Oh yes, okay. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let me add an additional element to `roads` so that the desired hash will have more than one key.

```
roads = [['1004', 'VIC'], ['1004', 'BRI'], ['1011', 'VIC'],
         ['1010', 'ACT'], ['1000', 'ACT'], ['1019', 'VIC'],
         ['1004', 'VIC'], ['1000', 'VIC]]
```

```
require 'set'
```

```
roads.each_with_object({}) do |(dc,st),h|     
  h[dc] = Set.new unless h.key?(dc)
  h[dc] << st
end.select {|k,v| v.size > 1}
   .transform_values(&:to_a)
  #=> {"1004"=>["VIC", "BRI"], "1000"=>["ACT", "VIC"]}
```

See [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Let's go through the steps.

```
f = roads.each_with_object({}) do |(dc,st),h|     
  h[dc] = Set.new unless h.key?(dc)
  h[dc] << st
end
  #=> {"1004"=>#<Set: {"VIC", "BRI"}>, "1011"=>#<Set: {"VIC"}>,
  #    "1010"=>#<Set: {"ACT"}>, "1000"=>#<Set: {"ACT", "VIC"}>,
  #    "1019"=>#<Set: {"VIC"}>}
```

Writing the block variables as `|(dc,st),h|` makes use of [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). This is a powerful technique with many applications.

Here, suppose we write:

```
enum = roads.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["1004", "VIC"], ["1004", "BRI"],...,
  #                  ["1000", "VIC"]]:each_with_object({})>
```

When the first element is generated and passed to the block the following is executed to assign values to the block variables.

```
(dc,st),h = enum.next
  #=> [["1004", "VIC"], {}]
```

resulting in:

```
dc #=> "1004"
st #=>"VIC"
h  #=> {}
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). [This article](https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/) is one of several that provides a fuller explanation of array decomposition.

Continuing,

```
g = f.select {|k,v| v.size > 1}
  #=> {"1004"=>#<Set: {"VIC", "BRI"}>, "1000"=>#<Set: {"ACT", "VIC"}>}
g.transform_values(&:to_a)
  #=> {"1004"=>["VIC", "BRI"], "1000"=>["ACT", "VIC"]}
```

---

There are two common variants to how `f` is computed. The first is

```
f = roads.each_with_object({}) do |(dc,st),h|
  (h[dc] ||= Set.new) << st
end
```

`h[dc] ||= Set.new` expands to `h[dc] = h[dc] || Set.new`. If `h` has a key `dc` this becomes `h[dc] = h[dc]`; else it becomes `h[dc] = nil || Set.new = Set.new`. A set `s` is returned and `s << st` is then executed. This works so long as `h` has no values equal to `nil`.

The second variant is

```
roads.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=Set.new}) do |(dc,st),h|
  h[dc] << st
end
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block and no argument. If `h` is defined

```
h = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=Set.new}
```

then, possibly after key-value pairs have been added, if `h` does not have a key `k`

```
h[k] = Set.new
```

is executed. In this context when `h[dc] << st` is encountered and `h` does not have a key `dc`, `h[k] = Set.new` is executed before `h[dc] << st`.

---

A variant of the initial solution is the following.

```
roads.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) {|(dc,st),h| h[dc] << st}
     .transform_values(&:uniq)
     .select {|k,v| v.size > 1}
```

Comment: Set.new is a nice idea to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 1):

If you already can get:

```rb
{"1004"=>[["1004", "VIC"], ["1004", "BRI"], ["1004", "VIC"]], "1011"=>[["1011", "VIC"]], "1010"=>[["1010", "ACT"]], "1000"=>[["1000", "ACT"]], "1019"=>[["1019", "VIC"]]}
```

With:

```rb
roads.group_by { |ro| ro[0] }
```

Then you just need to *select* the entries with *length* greater than 1.

```rb
roads.group_by { |ro| ro[0] }.select { |k, v| v.length > 1 }
```

And I get:

```rb
{"1004"=>[["1004", "VIC"], ["1004", "BRI"], ["1004", "VIC"]]}
```

Then we can map that down to just the names. Could be one line, but split up for demonstration.

```rb
roads.group_by { |r| r[0] }                  \
     .select { |k, v| v.length > 1 }         \
     .map { |k, v| [k, v.map { |x| x[1] }] } \
     .to_h
```

And the result is:

```rb
{"1004"=>["VIC", "BRI", "VIC"]}
```